# DropDownList and its initial value

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

How can I set the initial value of a drop downlist say to the word "Empty"..regardless to what i bind to it in the pageload or feed values dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this item manually and set the DropDownList's [AppendDataBoundItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) property to `true`.

For example (added on ASPX):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
   AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
   DataSource="myDataSource" 
   DataTextField="TextColumn" 
   DataValueField="IdColumn">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Empty..." Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

or in codebehind:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Empty...", "0", True))
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TextColumn"
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "IdColumn"
DropDownList1.DataSource = myDataSource
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create an new list item and then add it to the Drop Down. Do it in the Page_load function or data bind.

```
var emptyvalue = new ListItem("Empty...", "0");
DropDownItem.Items.Add(emptyvalue );
```

Comment: Are you meaning how to make the text align to the right? If so use css. `select {text-align:right;}`

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
DrpDwn_ProductType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Empty...", ""));
```